# wpf datagrid: how to manage it?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In my project I need to show some values in a grid/table. Values are taken by a List of objects, described as follows:

```
public class FixedPosition
{
    public int percentage;
    public HorizontalAlignment alignment;        
}
```

I need that the table has three headers:

- index
- % (to represent percentage)
- alignment

I've seen that there is an element in WPF called Datagrid that allows to add objects as rows of grid, but I need some help to manage it.

1. I create the headers in XAML, but how to fit headers with the FixedPosition object, without changing it, to have the correct data shown? I've tried to add the objects into the Datagrid, but I don't see them.
2. How can I allow to user to edit values directly in Datagrid in window?
3. How can I manage changing data into the Datagrid, that means how can I update object related to row after data changed into the Datagrid by user?

I haven't found tutorials about that.
If someone knows any other way to obtain the same result, please give me an help.
Thanks

EDIT:

regarding headers, I've added the field "index" to solve the problem. Now I can see and edit values in the grid by setting ItemsSource property correctly with the list of FixedPosition objects. Plus, I use the "Binding" property to bind each field with related attribute. Now I need to know how to have the combobox for alignment attribute, because if I use DataGridComboBoxColumn , I don't know how to give the binding with alignment attribute, because there is no Binding property for this column.

Comment: This tutorial is pretty good - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42548/MVVM-and-the-WPF-DataGrid

Comment: It seems not so simple...maybe I'm wrong but maybe there is something more simple around...I'm going to study it and looking around

Comment: The problem is that I can not have a DataGrid autogenerated passing a List, as described in the tutorial find here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/ I put the collection in this way this.FixedPositionDataGrid.ItemsSource = fixedPositionList; I see 4 rows (in the list there are 3 items), without headers and values (rows are collapsed)...any suggestion?